# Difference between Danam and Dharma?

Tags: dharma, terminology

What is the difference between danam and dharma I cannot find out the difference in any of the scriptures as Karna is called the dana warrior and Yudhishthira is called of dharma
Can anyone help me....?

Comment: See http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Dharma#Defining_Dharma and [Manusmriti 6.92](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200653.html). [Daana](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/D%C4%81na) (charity) is just a small subset of Dharma. Dharma encapsulates a lot of things.

Comment: I think Karna is called "Daan Shoora" ie.who is  brave in charity. Yudhishthira is called "Dharma Raja or Raj" ie. a king who is righteous. Dharma is just a short form of "Dharma Raja

Comment: Dana=Charity where as Dharma=Righteousness..Dana can be considered as just one of the many pillars of Dharma

Comment: @Rickross I have seen in a Dasavatharam movie that "Charity  performed for friuts is called DANA"  and  " Charity performed not for any friuts is called DHARMA" this was a speech between King Bali and Lord VAMANA as his sacrifice for achieving indralokaha. "is this correct or not ". If wrong please explain the correct one.

Comment: @sakthiYes the shastras say that Dana made out of desire of fruits bear less or no fruits..whereas nishakama dana brings longlasting bliss..